# string index out of range, this is and alternative method of regex

Tags: python, string

`this is and example of the data ->`
`[04/01/21, 10:56:27 AM] Name: message`
`this is the code->``

```
lenght = len(data)
messageList=[]
dateList=[]
for i in range (0,lenght):
  if data[i]=='[' and data[i+1].isdigit() and data[i+2].isdigit() and data[i+3]=='/' and data[i+21]==']':
    x= data[i+1:i+21]
    dateList.append(x) 
    a=i+24 
    for j in (a,342671):
      if (data[j]=='[' and data[j+1].isdigit() and data[j+2].isdigit() and data[j+3]=='/' ):
        y=data[i+24:j-1]
        messageList.append(y)
   
  elif data[i]=='[' and data[i+1].isdigit() and data[i+2].isdigit() and data[i+3]=='/' and data[i+22]==']':
    x= data[i+1:i+22]
    dateList.append(x)
    for j in (i+25,342671):
      if data[j]=='[' and data[j+1].isdigit() and data[j+2].isdigit() and data[j+3]=='/' :
        y=data[i+25:j-1]
        messageList.append(y)
```

`[image: this is the error]

just want to remove the error
using this i will split the data into date and message and then ill make a dataframe form it

Comment: indentation 2 spaces. I actually like this, but it seems that others prefer 4 spaces (convention).

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex here, with the help of the `str.extract` Pandas function:

```py
df[["date", "message"]] = df["msg"].str.extract(r'\[(.*?)\] (.*)')
```

I am assuming here that the message is everything which follows the `[04/01/21, 10:56:27 AM]` date.